# Selenium Python ElementNotVisibleException

Tags: python, selenium, authentication

I'm using Selenium with Python, and I'm trying to complete a login form, I've 
succeed to complete the username field, but could not complete the password. This is the html:

```
<div class="loginNotVodafone" style="">

        <form id="loginNotVodafone" name="loginNotVodafone" action="https://urlblabla" method="post">      
          <!-- // GDPR select -->

          <fieldset>
          <input type="text" id="userFake2" name="userFake2" value="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Username">
          <input type="hidden" id="user" name="UserName" class="hiddenTwo" value="">
          </fieldset>

          <fieldset>
          <input id="password" name="Password" value="" type="password" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Password">
          </fieldset>

        </form>
</div>
```

and this is my code:

```
inputuser = driver.find_element_by_id("userFake2")
inputuser.send_keys('email@email.com')
sleep(1);

password = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//fieldset[.//input[@id='password']]")
password.click()
sleep(1);
password.send_keys('password')
```

I always receive the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not 
visible
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\stefa\eclipse-workspace\main.py", line 36, in <module>
password.send_keys('password')
File "C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 479, in send_keys
'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
File "C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 628, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
File "C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Users\stefa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
(Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.99)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

**EDIT:**
with this commands i can let the cursor blink in the password field:

```
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*@id='loginNotVodafone']/fieldset[2]").click()
password.send_keys('password')
```

but got the error message:

```
password.send_keys('password')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

Comment: Can you post the full TraceBack

Comment: added in the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there was a problem in the xpath, so i've used an addon  called ChroPath for Chrome and it gave me the correct absolute and relative path

so the correct command was:

```
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/form[1]/fieldset[3]/input[1]").send_keys('password')
```

or relative Xpath:

```
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@id='loginNotVodafone']//input[@id='password']").send_keys('password')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `WebDriverWait`:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "Password")))
```

***Note:*** you have to add some imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

`WebDriverWait` will wait at least 10 seconds until element will be clickable and only then clicks on it. The whole code will be like this:

```
inputuser = driver.find_element_by_id("userFake2")
inputuser.send_keys('email@email.com')

password = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "Password")))
password.click()
sleep(1); # make sure, that you really need this pause
password.send_keys('password')
```

***EDIT:*** you can try also to use `JavaScript`:

```
inputuser = driver.find_element_by_id("userFake2")
inputuser.send_keys('email@email.com')

password = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", password)
sleep(1); # make sure, that you really need this pause
password.send_keys('password')
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but now i'm getting the "TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)", it still not find the password field

Comment: Is this field visible on the browser? Are you sure that this filed is in HTML you have posted?

Comment: I have added information to my answer, please have a look

Comment: i've updated the page's code with some other information (sorry i'm not and expert in this field).  The full Traceback is in the main post

Comment: have you tried `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", password)` ?

Comment: make sure that there is only one element with `id = password`. In dev tools have a look

Comment: i'll try your tip after same test, i've update the post in the meanwhile

Comment: @Stefano happy to hear it, can you share what has worked?

Comment: of course, i have added the solution in the answers , i will accept it in 2 days ( now i can't)